# Update Variable Arrays In Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export a list of users, get a random sample of those users, then remove that random sample from the original list.  If I manually add data to the array like this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692802.aspx) it seems to work fine.  But when I try to import from a csv or use Get-Content to get the data, it won't remove anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<#-->The first 4 lines are the same for all attempts.  Between attempts I exited PowerShell.<--#>

$Date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=Domain" -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties sAMAccountName |
Select-Object @{Name="User ID";Expression={$_."sAMAccountName"}}, @{Name="Date";Expression={$Date}} |
Export-Csv "C:\File.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#-->First Attempt<--#
$Import = Import-Csv C:\File.csv
$Sample = Get-Random -InputObject $Import -Count 20
$List = $Import -ne $Sample

#This shows 20.
$Sample.Count 

#These both show the same number instead of $List being 20 less than $Import.  
$Import.Count 
$List.Count

#-->Second Attempt<--#
$Import = Get-Content C:\File.csv 
$Sample = Get-Random -InputObject $Import -Count 20
$List = $Import -ne $Sample

#This shows 20.
$Sample.Count

#These both show the same number instead of $List being 20 less than $Import.  
$Import.Count
$List.Count

#-->Third Attempt<--#
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Import = Import-Csv C:\File.csv
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Sample = Get-Random -InputObject $Import -Count 20
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$List = $Import -ne $Sample

#This shows 20.
$Sample.Count

#These both show the same number instead of $List being 20 less than $Import.  
$Import.Count
$List.Count 

#-->Fourth Attempt<--#
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Import = Import-Csv C:\File.csv
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Sample = Get-Random -InputObject $Import -Count 20
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$List = $Import.Remove($Sample)

#This shows 20.
$Sample.Count

#This shows 1000.
$Import.Count

#This shows 0. 
$List.Count
```

Comment: I think you want this: `$List = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Import -DifferenceObject $Sample).InputObject`.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht
Thank you, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Where` statement to filter out the records that you do not want to include, such as:

```
$Import = Import-Csv C:\File.csv
$Sample = Get-Random -InputObject $Import -Count 20
$List = $Import | Where{$_ -notin $Sample}
```

Then `$List.count` should be `$Import.Count - $Sample.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

You want this as Alexander mentioned:

```
$List = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Import -DifferenceObject $Sample).InputObject | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }
```

The `$_.SideInidcator` will get you only the values that are in `$Import` and not in `$Sample`

EDIT:

Actually since the names are in both lists Alexanders method will work just fine.  But if you had values in `$sample` that weren't in `$Import` then you would get those  values too unless you did the sideIndicator method

Comment: When I add the `code` | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } `code` $List is empty.  It is doing what I want it to without it though, so I'll play around with this pipe later on to see what I can do with it.